# Kubernetes Network Policy - Allow specific IP

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I'm using Kubernetes on IBM cloud.

I want to create a network policy that denies all the incoming connections to a pod (which expose the app on port 3000 ), but which allows the incoming connections only from a specific IP (MY_IP).

I wrote this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
name: <MY_POLICY_NAME>
namespace: <MY_NAMESPACE>
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <MY_APP>
      env: <MY_ENV>
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: <MY_IP>/24
        except:
        - <MY_IP>/32
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
```

Unfortunately, this is not working because it blocks all the connections.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you remove the policy, it allows all the connections?

Comment: yes, without the policy all the connections are allowed.

Comment: how do you know the connection is coming from `<MY_IP>/24`?

Comment: I'm looking the logs of the ingress ALB. Because <MY_IP> is an ip of a server outside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In your policy as it is right now, you are allowing ingress from that CIDR, *except* for all traffic from your `<MY_IP>`. So it is blocking all traffic from your IP.

PS: Source IP preservation is disabled by default for Ingress in IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service. Make sure you've enabled it for your Ingress service: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_ingress.html#preserve_source_ip

Comment: I have enabled the source IP to keep the original one.
I also have updated the policy based on your feedback, I removed the except field and left only the cidr. However it still blocks all the incoming connections.